# How can we access input values in the then block of context promise in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, promise

How can we access input values in the then block of context promise in JavaScript? See the code snippet below. processInServer() may be invoked several times.

```
function processInServer(someData){
    return getPromise(someData).then(function(data) {  
      return {"input": someData, "output": data};
    });
}
var a1 = processInServer(someData1);
var a2 = processInServer(someData2);
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "input values". Do you mean the value of the `input` property? What do you mean by "in the then block of context promise"?

Comment: modified the code to make it clearer. Is a1.input always same as someData1 irrespective the sequence of response from the server.

Comment: @dipu: You can't do that. The variables a1 and a2 need to be assigned in the `then()` blocks.

Comment: @dipu Note, at updated `javascript` both `a1` and `a2` would be `undefined`, as no value is returned from `processInServer` function call.

Answer (score 1):

You could adjust `getPromise` to a constructor which returns an object. Set `someData`, `Promise` as properties of returned object. `someData` should then be accessible at object reference, as well as `Promise` object. Use `.then()` chained to promise set at object to review both promise value and input value.

```js
function getPromise(someData) {
  this.someData = someData;
  this.promise = Promise.resolve(someData * Math.random() * Math.PI);
}

var gp = new getPromise(123);
var result = gp.promise.then(function(data) {
  return {
    "input": gp.someData,
    "output": data
  };
});

result.then(function(result) {
  console.log(`result:${JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)}`,
              `gp:${JSON.stringify(gp, null, 2)}`)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you return a object in `then` function then it returns a new promise with the same object so you can do

```
getPromise(someData).then(function(data) {  
  return {"input": someData, "output": data};
}).then(function(obj) {
    console.log(obj.input);
    console.log(obj.output);
});
```

Comment: if you invoke getPromise() multiple times, I think someData will have the  value from latest invocation.

Comment: @dipu: No. Each new invocation of `getPromise` creates a new promise object so each invocation's `then` will only get that invocation's then while other invocation's `then` will get their own data. Promises are just an object oriented design pattern around asynchronous code. In JS they're implemented basically as a factory. They're not singletons. So each call to a promise generating function creates a new instance.